# The nested loop is producing this error: Non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r

I'm very new to R and I'm having trouble executing this script. The nested loop outputs a "Non-numeric argument to mathematical function" error. I'm not sure which argument in the nested loop is non-numerical? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

```
library(emdbook)

prev<-read.delim("shape.txt", header=T)
shape1<-prev$shape1
shape1<-as.numeric(shape1)
shape2<-prev$shape2
shape1<-as.numeric(shape2)

pvec <- seq(0, 1, length=298)

postvec<-data.frame(posterior=1:298)
dim(postvec)

for (i in 1:length(shape1)) 
{
    for (j in 1:length(shape2)) 
    {
    postvec[i]<- dbeta(pvec, shape1= shape1[i], shape2=shape2[j])
}
}
```

Comment: can you give some more context about what you are trying to do? Can you give us the contents of `prev`? Or a subset of it? You can type `dput(prev)` into your R console and copy the output into the question so we can recreate your data. I'm betting there are alternative ways to do what you want here without resorting to a double loop.

Comment: What does your inner loop do?  As far as I can tell, your code will overwrite `postvec` on each outer loop, i.e. you will end up a with a vector describing the results of the very last operation (where `i==length(shape1))`)

Comment: @Chase We are trying to estimate 95% Bayesian Credible Intervals for a proportion. For example, we are studying a disease in frogs and say for instance we detect 3 diseased animals from a total sample of 10 frogs. Our proportion (or disease prevalence) is 3/10, or 0.3. We consulted a colleague who told us that in the context of this function, Shape 1 = 1-mu, where mu = # diseased animals, and Shape 2 = 1+n-mu, where n=total sample size. So for our example Shape 1=1-mu=1-3=-2 and Shape 1=1+n-mu=1+10-3=8. Does any of this make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
prev<-read.delim("shape.txt", header=T)
shape1<-prev$shape1
shape1<-as.numeric(shape1)
shape2<-prev$shape2
shape1<-as.numeric(shape2)
```

Should that last line say:

```
shape2<-as.numeric(shape2)
```

?

Comment: ah, yes. Thanks! now I'm getting this error: Error in x[[jj]] <- v : attempt to select less than one element
Calls: [<- -> [<-.data.frame

Comment: oops hit enter before I was ready. I'm not sure if a nested loop is what I want here? Thanks for the help. Gonna do a little more research.

Comment: I don't know anything about R, or about what you're actually trying to achieve, so it's hard to give too much advice. However, nested loops are usually for a 2-dimensional kind of task. So if you have a matrix, you might loop over each row. Then within each row, you'd loop over each element in the row. If you just have 2 arrays that you're trying to process in parallel, just use a single loop, and index both arrays using the one variable. That's assuming your arrays are the same length. If not then you might need 2 loops, but do one after the other, rather than one within the other.